# parse the node with

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, html-parsing

I have the response of HTML page

```
     `<cite>www.<b>apple</b>.com/in/</cite>`
```

I have to parse this using Library 'https://github.com/topfunky/hpple/blob/master/'

```
            TFHppleElement * element6 = [childrenArr5 objectAtIndex:0];
            NSArray * arr = [element6 childrenWithTagName:@"cite"];
            NSLog(@"arr:%@ cnt:%d",arr,[arr count]);
            TFHppleElement * element7 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString * cite = [element7 text];
            NSLog(@"cite:%@",cite);
```

But i am not getting entire text, it just grab the "www." from , Please suggest something to get the entire text within the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text only gives you the text of ONE element. It ignores any children there might be.

- cite

  - TextNode: www.
  - b

    - TextNode: apple
  - TextNode: .com/in/

to get all text under a city tag ignoring any tags in between I think something like this should do

```
@interface THppleElement (textInlcudingChildren)
- (NSString*)textInlcudingChildren;
@end

@implementation THppleElement (textInlcudingChildren)
- (NSString*)textInlcudingChildren {
    NSMutableString *txt = self.text;
    for(id child in self.children)
        [txt appendString:[child textInlcudingChildren]];
    return txt;
}
@end
...

NSString * text = [element7 textInlcudingChildren];
NSLog(@"%@", text);
```